# How can I develop a formula to it's R expression

Tags: r, formula, lm

Say I have a r `formula` is there a way to develop this formula into it's R expression meaning ?
I assume R must do it somewhere in the `lm*` functions

Example:

`x + I(u*z) + x:z + u*v` would develop to `x + u*z + x*z + u + v + u*v`

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate as the accepted answer in the other question does not deal with `I(y/z)` or `x:z` as asked by the poster.

Comment: indeed it would be interesting to see if a real formula can be handled

Comment: @Joris Meys can you reopen please

Comment: @Constantinos hum... actually it kind of does, `I()` can just be `gsub`'ed

Comment: Fair enough. Similarly, you'd also need to replace `x:z` with `x*z`.

Comment: @statquant as the question stands now, it is an exact duplicate and the answers there give you the exact way of dealing with this (i.e. using `terms()`). Otherwise you have to specify what you mean with "develop to". Also specify the class of the variables, because if `x` and `z` are eg factors, things like `:` and `*` are interpreted completely different.

Comment: @JorisMeys The question is clear and gives an example, Constantinos was spot on. Anyway we got it by deriving from the link you mention. This can be close but is not a duplicate

Comment: @statquant for SO standards this is an exact duplicate. `I()` and interactions (`:`) are dealt with correctly using `terms()`. I don't close questions for the fun of it. I actually start typing my answer, got a list of "related questions" and found my answer almost literally between the answers of the duplicate question. Glad you solved it by now.

Comment: Not they are not, just try `attr(terms.formula(y~I(x)), "term.labels")` that's not what is required as per my above example